# Highchart.js - add custom key to series return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added the custom key (total) to the series array of Highcharts, and when I tried to call the 'total' value from the series, it returns undefined, the other value like name, and data will get return except for the 'total' key which I added myself. Is there a way to work around this?

Pleas see the code below:

```
$(function () {
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
            total: 200
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5],
            total: 300
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0],
            total: 400
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8],
            total: 500
        }]
    });

    var series = $('#container').highcharts().series;
    //var series_total = [];
    $.each(series,function(index,value){
           alert(value.total);
    });

});
```

And on fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/7eb6vfdp/2/

Comment: try console log `this.series[0].data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `alert(value.options.total);`

[edited fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7eb6vfdp/3/)

Comment: wow, options.total that all I need to add, thanks very much to solve my issue

Comment: @Mike glad to help .  just use `console.log()` it will help whenever you have problem